# optparse-applicative option with multiple values

Tags: haskell

I'm using `optparse-applicative` and I'd like to be able to parse command line arguments such as:

```
$ ./program -a file1 file2 -b filea fileb
```

i.e., two switches, both of which can take multiple arguments.

So I have a data type for my options which looks like this:

```
data MyOptions = MyOptions {
    aFiles :: [String]
  , bFiles :: [String] }
```

And then a `Parser` like this:

```
config :: Parser MyOptions
config = MyOptions
         <$> option (str >>= parseStringList)
             ( short 'a' <> long "aFiles" )
         <*> option (str >>= parseStringList)
             ( short 'b' <> long "bFiles" )

parseStringList :: Monad m => String -> m [String]
parseStringList = return . words
```

This approach fails in that it will give the expected result when just one argument is supplied for each switch, but if you supply a second argument you get "Invalid argument" for that second argument.

I wondered if I could kludge it by pretending that I wanted four options: a boolean switch (i.e. `-a`); a list of strings; another boolean switch (i.e. `-b`); and another list of strings. So I changed my data type:

```
data MyOptions = MyOptions {
    isA    :: Bool
  , aFiles :: [String]
  , isB    :: Bool
  , bFiles :: [String] }
```

And then modified the parser like this:

```
config :: Parser MyOptions
config = MyOptions
         <$> switch
             ( short 'a' <> long "aFiles" )
         <*> many (argument str (metavar "FILE"))
         <*> switch
             ( short 'b' <> long "bFiles" )
         <*> many (argument str (metavar "FILE"))
```

This time using the `many` and `argument` combinators instead of an explicit parser for a string list.

But now the first `many (argument str (metavar "FILE"))` consumes *all* of the arguments, including those following the `-b` switch.

So how can I write this arguments parser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aside from commands, `optparse-applicative` follows the [`getopts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/getopts.1posix.html) convention: a single argument on the command line corresponds to a single option argument. It's even a little bit more strict, since `getopts` will allow multiple options with the same switch:

```
./program-with-getopts -i input1 -i input2 -i input3
```

So there's no "magic" that can help you immediately to use your program like

```
./program-with-magic -a 1 2 3 -b foo bar crux
```

since `Options.Applicative.Parser` wasn't written with this in mind; it also contradicts the [POSIX conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html), where options take either one argument or none.

However, you can tackle this problem from two sides: either use `-a` several times, as you would in `getopts`, or tell the user to use quotes:

```
./program-as-above -a "1 2 3" -b "foo bar crux" 
# works already with your program!
```

To enable the multiple use of an option you have to use `many` (if they're optional) or `some` (if they aren't). You can even combine both variants:

```
multiString desc = concat <$> some single
  where single = option (str >>= parseStringList) desc

config :: Parser MyOptions
config = MyOptions
     <$> multiString (short 'a' <> long "aFiles" <> help "Use quotes/multiple")
     <*> multiString (short 'b' <> long "bFiles" <> help "Use quotes/multiple")
```

which enables you to use

```
./program-with-posix-style -a 1 -a "2 3" -b foo -b "foo bar"
```

But your proposed style isn't supported by any parsing library I know, since the position of free arguments would be ambiguous. If you really want to use `-a 1 2 3 -b foo bar crux`, you have to parse the arguments yourself.

Comment: the free arguments wouldn't be ambiguous if the arguments to `-a` were constrained to not begin with `-`, though.

Comment: Good answer. Want to emphasize not to use 'value' modifier when using some/many. If your opt parsing hangs, this may be the culprit.